# How to assign a transient value as a default value to another attribute in View Object - ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am new to adf and I am trying to provide a default value based on an sql statement to another attribute. For instance I have a table called Employee(emp_id,emp_version,emp_name...), which has a column emp_version and i want to provide a default value to emp_version with the following sql statement:

```
  select count(emp_id)+1
    from employees
```

In order to do this  I tried to create a transient field(testEmpversionTransient) and provide an sql statement as shown below:
[image]

However I am not able to assign the value from the testEmpversionTransient attribute to emp_version attribute, any idea how it can be acheived please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why create the transient? Why not just assign the default value to the attribute directly/ or use groovy to assign the transient value?

Comment: ohh thanks for your response @Joe do you know any online tutorial how i can assign default value directly please?

Comment: You just do the same thing you did for the transient attribute to the original attribute. One more option - use a database trigger to populate the value of that field on insert.

Answer (score 0):

Youre trying something like adding a default value to a certain field when entering data to your table right.

For that you don't need to change the SQL statement, all you have to do is adding the default value to the required field's **placeHolder** (located in the properties tab of that field)

```
placeholder="Default Value"
```

When you commit the changes to the Data Base, for that field the default value will be commited.